# Linux Column with value print

Tags: awk, command

i tried awk for selecting 2 columns but now, the fourth column is somewhere blank and has value at some places, how to filter only the which has values

```
a,b,c,
d,e,f,g
g,h,i
j,k,l,m
```

I need only

```
f,g
l,m
```

to be printed post this awk filtering

Comment: Show us what you have try so far.

Comment: awk -F "," '{print $3,$4}' test_awk_iden.txt | more, it give me two columns like first row is like
aaa
second is like bbb eee
third is like
ccc

and now i want only bbb eee in my output

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. Do you want to print all lines that have values in only the 1st and 2nd fields? What is the field separator in the file? Space? Tabs? Something else? Will the others exist but be empty or will there be no other fields?

Comment: this didn't work, inspite of adding the apostrophe before curly braces. okay i have a file with 4 fields seperated by comma. like below
a,b,c,
d,e,f,g
g,h,i
j,k,l,m

I need only below to be printed. only if 4th value is present is below
f,g
l,m

Comment: What didn't work? What apostrophe? What curly braces? Please [edit] your question and add a representative example of your file, including both lines that should be kept and lines that should not be kept, making sure all possible cases are covered (one field, two fields, empty fields etc.) and then add the output you would want from that example.

Answer (score 3):

The `test.txt` file content is

```
a,b,c,
d,e,f,g
g,h,i
j,k,l,m
```

`awk` with `-F` to specify comma as separator, and `$4` to specify 4th column.

```
awk -F',' '$4!="" {print $3","$4}' test.txt
```

to have the output

```
f,g
l,m
```

Comment: thanks Hans it worked....One more query if you can help...How to execute an awk script on multiple .gz extension files...need one output for all multiple .gz files

Comment: @SuryaShukla that is probably better to close this question and post another one for your new question and give me detailed information. I actually dont fully understand.

Comment: not able to post a new question...I have one awk script and I wish to execute that awk script on multiple .gz extension files without inflating them to full, due to low disk space. i need to run that awk script on multiple gunzip files, without unzipping them...I have one command (awk -f xxxxx.awk filename) but this it to execute it over one unzipped file. Instead I wish to execute it over multiple gunzip file without unzipping them

Comment: @SuryaShukla `zcat` might be the answer to you but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: zcat is for viewing the gunzip file but i need to execute the script over multiple gunzip files without inflating them or unzipping them

Comment: @SuryaShukla then add this to your question, please. We can't help you if you don't tell us what you actually need.

Comment: @SuryaShukla still I can't fullly understand. What I suggest is still closing this quesiton and post to the new question. Since seems you are asking completely different things.

Comment: @SuryaShukla regarding [i need to execute the script over multiple gunzip files without inflating them or unzipping them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/712837/linux-column-with-value-print#comment1350006_712859) - that's not possible with awk or any other **text** processing tool but anyway, it does need to be a new question. This questing being downvoted would just have blocked you from asking a new one for a day, you should be able to ask new questions now.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks